# Is it possible to query on a relation itself in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I am using the built-in database in Neo4J, and there is a relation between Person and Movie called REVIEWED. The relation itself has its own id and a rating property. Is it possible to query the REVIEWED relation and get its properties?

I have tried:

```
type Reviewed {
  _id: ID!
  rating: Int
}
```

and then, in the graphQL playground:

```
{
Reviewed{
  _id
  rating
}
```

}

EDIT: [Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVxHW.png)

Comment: It depends on the schema, and the graphql server that was made, why don't you try if it is possible at all by using GraphQL Introspection? https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/

Comment: I tried the examples in the guide, but it didn't work. I have included a picture of the relation and its properties in an edit of the post.